Problema de 500 internal server error en mi web
Estoy esperimentando varios problemas en mi pagina web marckitus.com.
Al principio nos dimos cuenta del problema cuando intentabamos comprar un producto y la pagina se quedaba cargando durante varios minutos y al final debaja un error. Además en esta web se venden cursos y estos deberian ponerse en tu cuenta cuando compras el producto, esto antes funcionaba perfectamente, pero hace ya casi 1 mes, no funciona y no deja el producto en tu cuenta, además de dar varios errores.
Yo pensaba que el problema solo estaba aqui hasta que intente cambiarle la contraseña a un usuario y al darle a actualizar usuario me dio el mismo problema, la pagina se quedaba cargando durante varios minutos y despues me aparece una pantalla en negro con un 500 internal server error. Adjunto una imagen de lo que pasa cuando intento actualizar un usuario con una informacion nueva.
(https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)
Para dar más detalles:
En la pagina web vendemos cursos online con Tutor LMS y woocommerce, usamos la pasarela de pago de stripe - woocommerce y el tema Divi, aunque como digo, hay mas errores que los de woocommerce, pero por si les sirve de utilidad esta informacion. Adjunto imagen de lo que pasa cuando compro un producto en en la web.
(https://i.sstatic.net/Wx8WM0ew.png)
He probado de mil formas diferentes.

Navegador incognito
Desactivar todos los plugins
cambiar a tema de wordpress
Actualizar wordpress y todos los plugins
Restaurar una version anterior de la web
Todo a la vez.
Cambiar el .htaccess con un codigo de wordpress


Busca el log de errores de tu web y alli deberias ver el porque te devuelve un error 500. Pueden ser muchas cosas, desde una version de php no soportada, hasta un código retocado sin querer que ahora da error.  A ciegas no se te puede ayudar.

En el debug.log tengo todos estos logs, envio captura y además escribo el log de hoy porque son muchos    PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in /home/u882012549/domains/marckitus.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 1987 [enlace](file:///C:/Users/alber/Downloads/debuglogwordpress.png)

Al parecer las credenciales que estás usando para conectar a la base de datos no son correctas.

Parece que en un punto el servidor se cae dando ese error, talvez tu server es malo por ser un server compartido o talvez hay un sub proceso que esta mermando los recursos del servidor, en cualquiera de los casos, no podemos ayudarte con la información que das, mejor contrata un developer que haga testing en tu servidor para encontrar el porque se cuelga y asi saber si es algun proceso o tu servidor el que debe ser cambiado.
